# RestAssured. Is it possible to log the body in a ResponseSpecification for all the tests?

Tags: rest-assured

I try to setup @BeforeClass for test inheriting and I need always to log the request body in all of my tests so I try to do so:

```
import static io.restassured.filter.log.LogDetail.*;

@BeforeClass
public void config() {
  RequestSpecification jsonServerRequestSpecification =
      new RequestSpecBuilder()
          .setBaseUri("http://localhost")
          .setPort(3000)
          .log(METHOD).log(URI).log(PARAMS)
          .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
          .build();

  ResponseSpecification jsonServerResponseSpecification =
      new ResponseSpecBuilder()
              .expectContentType(ContentType.JSON)
              .log(STATUS).log(BODY)
              .build();

  requestSpecification = jsonServerRequestSpecification;
  responseSpecification = jsonServerResponseSpecification;
}
```

but after running one of my tests I'm getting this:

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    http://localhost:3000/comments?postId=1&id=1
Request params: <none>
Query params:   postId=1
                id=1
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:     <none>

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see body don't log but I expected it from the @BeforeClass method.

RestAssured - v4.2.0 | Java - v8

Comment: Finally, I have resolved this issue by adding `.addFilter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())` to the RequestSpecification